# Ubuntu 20.04 - Wifi stop working

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

I installed ubuntu 20.04 where I had ubuntu 16.04, but first I removed the old version and then on that partition I installed the new version, since then ubuntu has a problem with wifi.

Wifi stop working and a question mark appears where the wifi icon is, then I turn off and turn on wifi and it starts to work again (the question mark is removed) but the same problem happen in a while.

Sometimes the problem occurs in about 5 minutes or it could even take about 1 hour or more.

So, there I am turning the wifi off and on many times when I'm using my computer haha.